# Destination Table is not cleared upon successful creation of the table

Tags: google-bigquery

When using Destination Table option in BQ console, I often find myself overriding again just created table with my next query. The reason for this is that "Destination Table" option is not cleared automatically upon successful creation of the table. I think clearing this option automatically will provide better user experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We're making a bunch of changes with the query options in the Web UI, this seems like a good improvement to make (I've made the same mistake before, and agree that it can be annoying). Can you file a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/ ?